# Magnitude of average velocity..

Tags: polar-coordinates

A particle is at the position with Cartesian components $(5.0 m, 4.0 m)$ and $5.0 s$ later it is at the position with components $(8.0 m, 0.0 m)$.  What is the magnitude of its average velocity?

I know the answer is $1.0 m/s$.

Answer (score 4):

Average velocity is defined as the change in position divided by the change in time.
$$
\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}
$$
In our case, we are given $\Delta t = 5 \textrm{ s}$. We calculate $\Delta x$ by subtracting the initial position from the final position.
$$
x - x_0 = (8, 0) - (5, 4) = (3,-4) \textrm{ m}
$$
Doing the divison, we have
$$
\text{average velocity } = \left(\frac{3}{5}, -\frac{4}{5}\right) \textrm{ m}/\textrm{s}.
$$
We calculate the magnitude using the formula for magnitude
$$
|{\text{average velocity}}|=\sqrt{\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^2+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^2} = 1 \textrm{ m}/\textrm{s}
$$

Comment: Could you explain how the formula for |average velocity| works. I'm brand new to physics and haven't had a math class in a while. What exactly is it finding? Thank you so much for any help you can offer!